# JQuery Highchats with multiple Json files

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts, blob

I am working with highcharts where I need to load various number of json files from cloud (blobstorage) to plot 1 chart. My concerns where

1. Is there a known limit for the number of data series, or for the number of json files that we could use as data sources?
2. Any performance concerns if generating the graph from multiple JSON files?
3. Any way to add all the files in a directory in cloud and loop it using Jquery/JS?

I have googled so many articles but couldn't find any perfect suggestion. Can any one suggest some articles or related points?

Comment: 1. For a Chart, you can add as many series as possible from various number of sources, you just have to create the series. Highchart api doesn't concern how many data sources you have as long as you define the series.

2. It depends how quickly you can download data on to the browser. Since Highchart is a javascript api, it will do all the processing on the client side.

3. You may not be able to iterate through a directory, but you can make a js file with an array which contains all the file names of the js file in the said folder